# Kinesis Stream to S3 Backup using Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using AWS Kinesis Stream that is containing customer transactions. I want to backup the transactions into S3 before start processing them. How can I use bare Kinesis Firehose to backup the transactions from Kinesis Stream without running any Lambda or other computing component for it?

Comment: you can not do this without any lambda function or custom code running on a ec2. Kinesis stream is not capable of writing to firehose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the order of your Kinesis building blocks:

1. Instead of writing into Kinesis Stream, write into Kinesis Firehose that is directed to S3.
2. Run Kinesis Analytics (KA) application to read the events from your Kinesis Firehose (KF), and write them to a Kinesis Stream (KS). You can use the functionality of KA to do some of the filtering, aggregation and joins that you would otherwise run in your code (Lambda or KCL).